# Reasonable values for thread_cache_size in relation with Connections

Tags: mariadb, connections, cache, size

I want to know reasonable values for thread_cache_size in relation with the connections that you have. Which is the good proportion? And which proportions do you handle in relation with your clients connected?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you do any research? Are the recommendations from the manual not sufficient in your environment?

Comment: I think i didn't do enough research, but i read something on another Stack community bout Mysql's documentation says: "Threads_created / Connections (the % of connections that lead to the creation of new threads) is rather low. If you take the MySQL docs literally ("most"), the value should be < 50%."   https://serverfault.com/questions/408845/what-value-of-thread-cache-size-should-i-use       

But i can't really foun this answer on documentation.

Comment: @MatiasRuiz - Perhaps you could add this information to the question, especially if it's the motivation for the question in the first place (as opposed to using the recommendations from the manual, as mustaccio suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that `thread_cache_size` controls a "cache".  It is the number of threads (or processes, depending on the OS) to keep open just in case another connection request comes soon.  There is *some* cost in creating a thread. (This depends on the OS, etc.)

For Windows, `thread_cache_size` should be zero.  (Sorry, I don't have a reference stating that.)

If `thread_cache_size / max_connections` < 2% or > 15%, it *may* be poorly tuned.

If `Threads_running / thread_cache_size` > 2, then the cache *may* not be big enough.  (This depends on whether the number of connections is stable or fluctuating wildly.)

I suggest that `Threads_created / Connections` is not a good metric -- What if you have only one Connection/sec or 1000 Connections/sec?  Hence, I prefer this:  **If `Threads_created / Uptime` > 3/second, I suggest that the cache needs increasing.**

In a survey of systems, only 10% had `Threads_created / Uptime` > 0.26 / sec.

MySQL 5.6.8 automatically computes thread_cache_size based on max_connections.

MariaDB 10.2 takes a different approach; it "increases value of thread_cache_size to 32; adds 5 minute timeout before automatically removing threads from thread cache."  This feels like a good algorithm.

**Bottom line:  One should rarely have to worry about `thread_cache_size`.**